# Copying module, using the translation strings from the copied module

Tags: module, module-params

I regularly copy a existing module like mod_articles_news and I'd like to do some custom fields and things on it. But when I do this the translation strings don't get translated anymore. I keep using the languages tags in the xml file that are already there, but that seems to not work.

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_articles_news.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_articles_news.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Does anyone know how to make sure that these tags are still getting translated? Do i need to copy the language files or somethign?

Comment: What is the reason for or function of the new module you are creating? I am wondering if you are creating new copies of modules when perhaps there is a better way that perhaps would suit your needs.

Comment: I'd like to add some extra fields in the configuration without overriding the core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are copying `mod_articles_news` to create a new module called '`mod_my_new_module` and in the `mod_my_new_module.xml` you leave the `<languages>` settings the same as you have pasted in your question above? And the problem is when you install your new Module the MOD_TEXT_STRING doesn't get translated?

The `<language>` elements of the .xml file are only used during installation to tell the installer where to the find the language files(.ini & .sys.ini) you have provided in your installation file(.zip file) so that they can be copied to the Language folders of the Joomla instance. If you aren't providing any language files then the above two statements should be producing an error on installation they can't be found.

When your Module is called the processing tries to automatically resolve the name of your language files, expecting them to be called `mod_my_new_module.ini` and `mod_my_new_module.sys.ini` and because you haven't supplied during installation any that they are not found.

You need to copy/create your own language files using the naming conventions outlined in the documentation and include them when you install your new module.

You could force the module to load the language files for `mod_articles_news` but if you follow the normal process then it isn't required.

Updated....

If you want to just copy the files and rename them to match your new module name in the Language directory and then can continue to use Discover to find them that is quickest approach.

However if you want to learn how to create a module 'properly' then read some of the tutorials on creating modules and extension manifest & language files as you will find it more useful than relying on Discover.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what is happening. I just copy them and use Discover to install them. Forcing the language files for mod_articles_news is the fastest method though, do you mind explaining how to do that?

Comment: Thanks i have copied the files and renamed them now its working again